# How to handle multiple schemas in a single migrate with flyway

Tags: flyway

I'm totally new to Flyway but I'm trying to migrate a number of identical test databases using the docker-compose flyway+mysql arrangement described in https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker

As far as I can tell, the `migrate` command can take multiple schemas in its `-schemas` argument but it only seems to apply the actual SQL migration to the first schema in the list.

For example, when I run the migrate with `schemas=test_1,test_2,test_3`, flyway creates all three databases but only creates the tables specified in the migration file on the first `test_1` database.

Is there a way to apply the SQL migration file to all the schemas in the list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to leave this question up in case someone can still answer how multiple schemas is useful if the migration file isn't applied to all databases in the list. But, I was able to handle multiple databases in a docker-compose by overriding the flyway `entrypoint` and `command`.

So now my docker-compose service looks like:

```
services:
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:6.1.4
    volumes:
      - ./migrations:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - db
  entrypoint: ["bash"]
  command: > -c "/flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:mysql://db -schemas=test1 migrate;
                 /flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:mysql://db -schemas=test2 migrate"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was breaking up my migrations into separate executions in my docker-compose file along with [docker-postgresql-multiple-databases](https://github.com/mrts/docker-postgresql-multiple-databases) as follows:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  postgres-db:
    image: 'postgres:13.3'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: 'customers,addresses'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'pocketlaundry'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'iceprism'
    volumes:
      - ./docker-postgresql-multiple-databases:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    expose:
      - '5432' # Publishes 5432 to other containers (addresses-flyway, customers-flyway) but NOT to host machine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  addresses-flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:7.12.0
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/addresses -schemas=public -user=pocketlaundry -password=iceprism -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
      - ./sports-ball-project/src/test/resources/db/addresses/migrations:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    links:
      - postgres-db

  customers-flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:7.12.0
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/customers -schemas=public -user=pocketlaundry -password=iceprism -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
      - ./sports-ball-project/src/test/resources/db/customers/migrations:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    links:
      - postgres-db
```